boto3 cloudfront.create_invalidation "Your request contains one or more invalid invalidation paths"
I have the following code:
logger.info(
    "Invalidating cache...",
    extra={
        "bucket": event.bucket_name,
        "distribution_id": DISTRIBUTION_ID,
        "index_paths": index_paths,
    },
)
cloudfront.create_invalidation(
    DistributionId=DISTRIBUTION_ID,
    InvalidationBatch={
        "Paths": {"Quantity": len(index_paths), "Items": index_paths},
        "CallerReference": context.aws_request_id,
    },
)

I have run it many times successfully with different args but this time I got the error:

An error occurred (InvalidArgument) when calling the CreateInvalidation operation: Your request contains one or more invalid invalidation paths.

The preceding log line showed:
    "index_paths": [
        "index.html",
        "Movies/index.html"
    ],

These paths both exist (checked bucket in aws console).
One of them will have been newly created, and I suspect this may be the problem? i.e. the file had not been requested and cached yet?
It's a pain for me to rewrite the code so that it can identify creates vs updates and only invalidate the updates. Also even with updates how am I to know if it was requested and cached yet?
Can anyone confirm or point to docs suggesting cause of this error?

Paths should start with /.
Use index_paths like.
    "index_paths": [
        "/index.html",
        "/Movies/index.html"
    ],


aha, this seems to be correct, thank you!

...additionally: the paths have to urlencoded (e.g. in python with urllib.parse.quote)
